# Explaining the comparative form of "numb"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, pronunciation-vs-spelling, comparatives

The most common definition I have of numb is:

1. "Deprived of the power of sensation."
2. "Deprived of feeling or responsiveness."

These definitions show up in nearly the same form in multiple dictionaries, yet I see comparative and superlative forms "number" and "numbest" listed as well. I understand numb to mean complete deprivation of feeling, and so here's my question.

I had a student write the sentence: *His fingers got number the longer he stayed outside.* She asked if it was correct (because the spelling looked funny to her; it looked like number, as in "the number seven"), and I told her that numb didn't need a comparative form because it implied **complete** lack of sensation. I told her she could phrase a sentence *His fingers slowly became numb...* to signify that he was getting colder, but that she should not use numb in a comparative or superlative sense. Can somebody explain to me the reasoning for the comparative and superlative forms of this word. As well, I have the same problem with "wet, wetter, wettest."

Comment: I think this question applies to a LOT of words, and so I would re-phrase it to ask: How should I explain that words have varying degrees of force that definitions do not account for?

Comment: It's one of the edge cases in English. Sure, you can use the comparative form *number*, but if you're a careful writer who doesn't want to cause a hitch in the reading of your prose, chances are you'll choose to rephrase.

Comment: I think it's General Reference that words like *numb, wet,* etc., aren't "absolute", so in principle they can form comparatives and superlatives. It's just that in practice people normally favour [more numb](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22more+numb%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) over "number" to avoid potential confusion (esp. in the written form).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Consider *dead, deader, deadest*.

Comment: I think you have answered this yourself in the first comment: *numb*, *wet*, and even *dead* are not necessarily absolutes. You may suffer a partial loss of sensation; you may be incompletely moistened; one performance hall may be substantially less resonant than another.  –The orthographic ambiguity of *number*, however, is a different matter.

Comment: @tchrist: I've never understood why we say ["deader than a doornail"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22deader+than+a+doornail%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but my problem there is with the *doornail* - I don't have a problem with *degrees of deadness* (but John Cleese had some difficulty explaining exactly [*how* dead his parrot was!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIrBMt4eiRk) :)

Comment: "Mind! I don't mean to say that I know, of my own knowledge, what there is particularly dead about a door-nail. I might have been inclined, myself, to regard a coffin-nail as the deadest piece of ironmongery in the trade. But the wisdom of our ancestors is in the simile; and my unhallowed hands shall not disturb it, or the Country's done for. You will therefore permit me to repeat, emphatically, that Marley was as dead as a door-nail." *A Christmas Carol*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues involved here.

1. The pronunciation of final nasal-stop clusters like /-mb/ and /-ŋɡ/ with suffixes.
2. The use of the comparative and superlative degrees, and their meanings.

(1) is the reason why the spelled word *number* (meaning *more numb*) "looked funny". In print, there is already a word spelled that way, though it's pronounced differently, so most people wouldn't notice it in real language, only in writing:

- *This is number* /'nəmbər/ *twenty-seven.*
- *My left ring finger is number* /'nəmər/ *than my left index finger.*

In other words, the one *number* /'nəmbər/ doesn't rhyme with the other *number* /'nəmər/. The same is true for *singer*, which doesn't rhyme with *finger*. And for the same reason; English words ending in /mb/ or /ŋɡ/ dropped the final stop and kept the nasal. Except /nd/, though that's elided to /n/ now most of the time; however, that isn't reflected in the spelling. Except on the internet.

There's even another minimal pair, both spelled *longer*:

- The adjective *long* /lɔŋ/ plus the comparative *-er* produces /'lɔŋɡər/ 'more long', **with** /ɡ/
- The verb *long* plus the agentive *-er* produces /'lɔŋər/ 'one who longs', **without** /ɡ/

That's issue (1).

Issue (2) has been adequately dealt with in the comments; the initial confusion seems to be due to the common mistake of expecting literal dictionary definitions of grammatical terms to say anything useful about how grammar actually works. Dictionaries list **some** meanings of **some** words in **some** contexts; but they don't tell you about grammar. For that, one consults a Grammar, not a Dictionary.